Both increment and decrement in While loop in matrix in python
I created a 15 x 15 matrix in a pandas dataframe type. I want to make changes in some cells, following this logic:

The diagonal of the matrix is set to 0
In each row, if 0 appears in any position, the values in the next/ previous 5 columns should be updated to 1. (df.iloc[i][j] = 0 --> df.iloc[i][j+5] = 1 or df.iloc[i][j-5] = 1

Input (every cell is 0.9):
row, col = 15, 16
a = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[0.9]*col]*row)
a = a.loc[ : , a.columns != 0]


Expected output:

Below is my current script (which keeps running without an end):
row, col = 15, 16
a = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[0.9]*col]*row)
a = a.loc[ : , a.columns != 0]
column3 = list(a)
for i, j in a.iterrows():
    for k in column3:
        if k == i + 1:
            a.iloc[i][k] = 0


for i, j in a.iterrows():
    for k in column3:
        step = +5 if k <=5 else -5
        while k <= len(a.index):
            if a.iloc[i][k] == 0:
                k += step
                a.iloc[i][k] = 1

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
a 

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Is the process iterative or vectorial? I.e. if a cell is 0 and updates the next cells, should those no longer be considered if they were initially 0?

Also please provide a [mre] (i.e. code to set up the input) and the matching expected output

I think it is iterative. Every cell is hardcoded 0.9 in the beginning. Once the diagonal is updated to 0, there's only 1 cell being 0 in each row.

Can you provide a [mre] (input+expected output) as requested? That would clarify the logic

Both inputs and my workings are in the above block of code, I'll edit my post to clarify which is the input then.

Sorry about the input. However for the expected output, it's unclear. You said your code "keeps running without an end". So what is the expected output? How many iterations do you expect?

I explained the logic and attached a screenshot of expected output. I'm not sure about my code, so I pasted there to ask for others' opinions and where in my script is wrong.

Got it thanks, see a numpy approach below

Thanks a lot! Yours is much cleaner and the result is as expected.

You're welcome, note that since your array's shape is a multiple of 5, the exact behavior to use if it's not could need a tweak.

I would use numpy here and build a mask with roll:
# distance to 0
N = 5

# replace diagonal with 0
np.fill_diagonal(a.values, 0)

# build mask
m = (a==0).to_numpy()

# apply mask iteratively
for i in range(1, a.shape[1]//N):
    a[np.roll(m, i*N, axis=1)] = 1

Variant using pandas' shift:
N = 5

np.fill_diagonal(a.values, 0)
m = (a==0)

for i in range(1, a.shape[1]//N):
    a[m.shift(i*N, axis=1, fill_value=False)] = 1
    a[m.shift(-i*N, axis=1, fill_value=False)] = 1

Output:
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15
0   0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9
1   0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9
2   0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9
3   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9
4   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0
5   1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9
6   0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9
7   0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9
8   0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9
9   0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0
10  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9
11  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9  0.9
12  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9  0.9
13  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0  0.9
14  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  1.0  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.9  0.0

Output as image for clarity:

